What is $\min_x\max_y f(x,y)$, when two saddle points are known
Given a continuously differentiable function $f(x,y)$ with two saddle points, $(x_1,y_1)=(1,1)$ and $(x_2, y_2)=(-0.99,1)$, with their function values 2 and 1.99 respectively.
Based on this information, can we tell what is the value of $\min_x\max_y f(x,y)$? If so what is the value?
If you can provide the pointers to it, it would be appreciated. My knowledge about saddle point is only limited to its definition
$$f(x,y^*)\leq f(x^*,y^*)\leq f(x^*,y). $$

Hi man, have you plotted the graph ? Indeed you can see that a saddle point correspond to a local $x^$ solution of $\min_x \max_y f(x,y)$  but also the dual problem $y^$ solution of $\max_y \min_x f(x,y)$ and $\min_x \max_y f(x,y)= \max_y \max_x f(x,y)$ that three conditions are to get a saddle point.

I construct a related example on wolfram by typing "saddle points of 0.5(0.5*(x-1)^2+2.9sin^2(x-1)-0.5(y-1)^2)+0.5(0.5*(x+1)^2+3sin^2(x+1)-0.5(y+1)^2)". You can see there are two saddle points but I am not sure how min max of that function can be computed.
